# Jboss EAP 6.3 integration with OracleAQ jms

Tags: jms, jboss6.x, oracle-aq

I have application working on Jboss eap 6.3 and Hornetq queue for jms. I have to change queue from hornetq to OracleAQ. Is there any ready resource-adapter to connect it or I have to write new one for my own? I will be gratefull for any tips how can i achieve that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Oracle AQ's administered JMS objects (e.g. connection factories and destinations) must be looked up via a database connection (or perhaps LDAP) rather than JNDI. Nothing shipped with JBoss EAP can do this.

I propose to check with Oracle for information regarding a JCA resource adapter that they might provide for integration with other Java EE application servers like JBoss EAP.